# Apply a random color on each feature of a featurecollection

Tags: google-earth-engine, visualisation

I'm working in the JavaScript code editor and I would like to visualize features created from the `reduceToVector` function.

The best way to visually assesses that the algorithm match my expectation would be to assign a random color to each feature. This function exists for Images:

```
Map.addLayer(image.select("label").randomVisualizer(), null, 'random')
```

Is there a way to perform the same trick with a `featureCollection` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing out-of-the-box that I'm aware of. Below is my stab at implementing something like this.

```
var featureCollection = ee // Create some random features
  .FeatureCollection(
    ee.List.sequence(1, 20).map(function (_) {return ee.Feature(null) })
  )
  .randomColumn('x')
  .randomColumn('y')
  .randomColumn('buffer')
  .map(function (f) {
    return ee.Feature(
      ee.Geometry.Point([f.getNumber('x'), f.getNumber('y')])
        .buffer(f.getNumber('buffer').multiply(10000))
    )
  })

var viz = randomVisualizer(featureCollection)
print(viz)

Map.centerObject(featureCollection)
Map.addLayer(viz)


function randomVisualizer(featureCollection) {
  return featureCollection
    .randomColumn('random')
    .map(function (f) {
      var randomHex = f.getNumber('random').multiply((Math.pow(2, 24) - 1)).round().int().format('%x')
      var color = ee.String('000000').cat(randomHex).slice(-6) // Pad with 0 to length of 6
      return f.set('style', {
        color: color
      })
    })
    .style({styleProperty: 'style'})
}
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/14cb6b33c4c59b1a794354b5b875c9a9

Comment: sorry for the late comment. I think it could work but I don't find the `ee.Color`object that you are using here in the documenation. I assume it's comming from this file https://gist.github.com/schwehr/3d72e09263e2341167b12f619ca5d4b2 how should I import the package ?

Comment: I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think the trick is to just use the strange `paint` function (see [doc](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/feature_collections_visualizing)), so that you can then use `randomVisualizer`! This is easy, as long as your polygon id variable is numeric (for paint).

Code ([link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/63eda6e11a218638e6b47a1bd883dc68)) showing the administrative units for Ukraine:

```
// Load some data:
var countries = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL_SIMPLIFIED_500m/2015/level1");
var regions = countries.filter(ee.Filter.eq("ADM0_NAME", "Ukraine"))


// Do the strange paint operation, see https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/feature_collections_visualizing
var empty = ee.Image().byte();

var outline = empty.paint({
  featureCollection: regions,
  color: 'ADM1_CODE',
  width: 3
});

// now map with randomVisualizer
Map.centerObject(regions);
Map.addLayer(outline.randomVisualizer())
```

result:

[image]